# Remove ads from embedded videos (uploaded by me)

Tags: advertising, youtube

I have created a youtube channel and uploaded several original videos to that channel, for the purpose of embedding them into my website.

Problem is ads are being displayed like so:

[image]

My embed code is:

```
<iframe width="640"  type="text/html" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID?rel=0&html5=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

I have googled this issue and found many details on how to remove them but none have worked.

I have tried:

Channel > Advanced > Allow advertisements to be displayed alongside my videos OFF

Channel > Status and features > Verified account, and all in good standing

Channel > Status and features > Monetization is OFF

Video manager > Videos > List does not show a $ icon

Video manager > Videos > Edit individual video, see below:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed now - for anyone else with a similar issue - the problem was that there was a copyright claim on the video. This means Google will display ads regardless of your settings (so it seems), and I presume, share the revenue with copyright holder.

Although the video was an original work, there was background music which was not original! There is an option on YouTube to remove the tracks, but it did not remove 100% of the audio so I just stripped the audio locally and uploaded it again. No ads now.